# python nose plugins hook methods not work

Tags: python, nose

I want to use nose to run my test suites written by extends from unnittest.TestCase.
and i have a plugin which overrides the hook method: startTest() stopTest() beforeTest()..

below is my code:

```
names = ['module.testclass.testMethod1','module.testclass.testMethod2']
tests = []
for i in names:
    tests.append(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName(i))

suites = unittest.suite.TestSuite(tests)

inputs = ['','--verbosity=2', '--with-my-plugin']

nose.run(argv=inputs, suite=suites)
```

but i find all the hooks method in my-plugin like: `startTest()` `stopTest()` `beforeTest()` `afterTest()` all not be called. could some one tell me why? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should use the standard format provides by nose to search test method:

names = ['module:testclass.testMethod1','module:testclass.testMethod2']